# AOT build trying to import from @types instead of actual module

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular2-aot

When trying to add a service from the [auth0-js](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js) package to the DI container the build attempts to load the `index.js` file from the `node_modules/@types/auth0-js/index.js` directory instead of `node_modules/auth0-js/index.js`.

```
[21:50:57] 'build.bundles.app.aot' errored after 784 ms
[21:50:57] Error on fetch for @types/auth0-js/index.js at file:///Users/llwt/src/testing/angular-seed-advanced/node_modules/@types/auth0-js/index.js
    Loading dist/tmp/web.module.ngfactory.js
    Loading dist/tmp/main.web.prod.js
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/llwt/src/testing/angular-seed-advanced/node_modules/@types/auth0-js/index.js'
    at Error (native)
```

I feel like I must be missing something basic here. I've reproduced the issue in a fork of the Angular-Advanced-Seed by Nathan walker which can be found [here](https://github.com/llwt/angular-seed-advanced/commit/c84612bf259f01e64c727c4133fd25da21efaaef).

The package is being imported like so:

```
import { WebAuth } from 'auth0-js';
// ...
export function authHttp() {
  return new WebAuth({
    domain: 'foo',
    clientID: 'bar',
  });
}
// ...
@NgModule({
//...
  providers: [
    { provide: WebAuth, useFactory: (authHttp) },
    // ...
```

Let me know if there is any more specific info I can provide to help debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this in the future, it turned out that there was an error in the type definition of the `auth0-js` library that was causing the build to fail.

**Edit:** For anyone looking at this now. The issue is still there and being tracked in [this Definitely Typed issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11583).

Comment: @JasonSpradlin Edited with a link to the Definitely typed issue. I dropped a comment in there with a naïve solution that may or may not work for you. Basically comes down to someone needing to update the auth0-js type definitions.

Comment: To expound on the solution mentioned in the definitely typed issue.  Injecting an instance of WebAuth from your module into your AuthService factory seems to cause the bug to present itself during AOT Compilation.  Instead of injecting an instance of WebAuth, the example shows simply instantiating a WebAuth directly in the AuthService constructor.  This resolved our issue, but did make unit testing a little more difficult, as we couldn't just inject a mock WebAuth instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem..
Shortly:
This problem is somehow cause by DI of your WebAuth.
You must initialize WebAuth like this:

```
import { WebAuth } from 'auth0-js'

class AuthService {
    auth0 = new WebAuth(config);

    constructor(private otherDependency: OtherDependency) {}
}
```

This complicates mocking WebAuth in your tests.
I was able to mock it with Jest simply by:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    require('auth0-js').WebAuth = function() {
      return webAuthMock;
    };
});
```